# Check if an array contains any element of another array and highlight the ones from another array - React native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have an array of elements which are displayed as tags. For example:

```
["apple","banana","pineapple","grape"]
```

displayed as ==>
*apple* *banana* *pineapple* *grape*

is the array i have.

For a  **TextInput** `onChangeText`, a debounced socket-call is initiated with the text entered and after processing i will be getting an array of elements matching the text passed.

For example, I will be getting `["apple","banana"]` from the websocket response and it should be displayed in the tags as===>
***apple*** ***banana*** *pineapple* *grape*

where **apple** and **banana** are highlighted.

How to implement it?

**--update---**
**This is how my array looks like**

```
var originalArray = [
      { id: 1, name: "apple" },
      { id: 2, name: "banana" },
      { id: 3, name: "pineapple" },
      { id: 4, name: "grape" },];
    ];
var receivedArray = [
      { id: 1, name: "apple" },
      { id: 2, name: "banana" },];
```

Comment: Can you please add code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I was about to implement it. What i need to do is to highlight the elements, which is recieved from the backend along with the orginal array elements.

Answer (score 2):

You may find all index that the received element appearing in the original array then work on the found indices

```
var originalArray = ["apple","banana","pineapple","grape"];
var receivedArray = ["apple", "banana"];
var foundIndices = originalArray.map(el => receivedArray.includes(el) ? true : false)
// Highlight copy version of originalArray based on foundIndices
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop with `includes` (or even `indexOf`) perhaps:

```js
function dothing(){
  let mainarr=main.value.split(",");
  let filtarr=filter.value.split(",");
  for(var i=0;i<mainarr.length;i++)
    if(filtarr.includes(mainarr[i]))
      mainarr[i]="<i><b>"+mainarr[i]+"</b></i>";
  log.innerHTML=mainarr.join(" ");
}
dothing();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="main" oninput="dothing()" value="a,b,c"><br>
<input type="text" id="filter" oninput="dothing()" value="a,b"><br>
<div id="log"></div>
```